# Imagination PowerVR SDK examples fail to be executed on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, opengl-es-2.0

I run into Visual Studio and I get an error and ask a question.

I installed POWERVRSDK_2017 and ran OGLESHelloAPI.sln which is a sample file after installation. After the execution, the program was terminated with no response because it was executed after the build without touching the code.

The error occurred in DynamicEgl.h when debugging was executed, and the error content was 'Unhandled exception at 0x760BB3E5 in OGLESHelloAPI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.'

```
"DynamicEgl.h"

inline EGLDisplay DYNAMICEGL_FUNCTION(GetDisplay)(EGLNativeDisplayType display_id){
typedef EGLDisplay(EGLAPIENTRY * PROC_EGL_GetDisplay)(EGLNativeDisplayType display_id);
static PROC_EGL_GetDisplay _GetDisplay = (PROC_EGL_GetDisplay)::egl::internal::getEglFunction(::egl::internal::EglFuncName::GetDisplay);
return _GetDisplay(display_id);
}
```

I attached the code. _GetDisplay seems to check for errors, but I do not understand.
How can we solve this problem? Thank for your advise

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with the fact that it is "PowerVRSDK_2017" and you are trying to use Visual Studio 2013. If it's not too much trouble, you can get Visual Studio 2017 and see if it works with that.

Comment: This seems like something you should ask the package author about rather than asking those who know little or nothing about it. If there is no support for VS 2013, they should be able to tell you.

Comment: From the package name I guess you are talking about [tag:opengl-es] and not about desktop OpenGL. Are you sure that your PC supports the required opengl-es version?

Comment: @user4261590 I tried it first in Visual Studio 2017 but it was not. The project was launched in 2013 as if it were a 2013 version, but it did not work either. Thank you for answer:)

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thank you for answer. When I run the current project, I can not find libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll and I can not proceed with the code execution.

Comment: @BDL You commented on my article yesterday :) The current version of OpenGL on my computer is 4.6. The project seems to be using OpenGL 2.0, but as I said in the above comment, I do not have two files, so I do not seem to have a line.

Comment: The project seems to be using OpenGL-**ES** 2.0. But that shouldn't be a problem when your card supports OpenGL 4.6. If you encounter something with egl in the name, then you are usually using the es (embedded system) variant of GL. You might consider taging your questions with [tag:opengl-es] instead of [tag:opengl] to get experts from that field looking at your question.

Comment: @BDL Oh yes. You have modified the tag. Thank you every time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed powerVR, I clicked Accept Path setting during the installation process and finally it worked normally. I used visual studio 2017.